# Must be superuser to mount - even though /etc/fstab option includes users

Tags: mount, fstab, dvd

I am trying to set up the Automatic Ripping Machine (nickname for which, sadly, is arm) on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system with latest updates.

Part of the installation was to put the following line into /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sr0  /mnt/dev/sr0  udf,iso9660  users,noauto,exec,utf8  0  0
```

And a requirement is that the mount point /mnt/dev/sr0 be created - this is where the daemon will mount the inserted DVD or CDROM.  This has been created, as follows:

```
ls -ld /mnt/dev/sr0
drwxrwxrwx 2 arm arm 4096 Sep  9 15:36 /mnt/dev/sr0
```

The issue is that, even though 'users' is set as the first option in /etc/fstab, the user (arm) gets error "mount: /mnt/dev/sr0: must be superuser to use mount."

As I read the documentation for /etc/fstab, it sounds like we should not see this message.  I've also found indication (not at all clear) that this entry in /etc/sudoers will allow users named accordingly to perform mount.  But it has not improved my situation:

```
arm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount, /usr/bin/umount
```

What must be done in order to allow a normal user to mount this device to /mnt/dev/sr0?  (BTW: apparently I cannot configure a different mount point, but I'm not convinced that's the problem anyway.)

Comment: Read `man 8 mount;man 5 fstab`. The word you need is "`user`". "`users`" has a different effect.

Comment: Thanks, @waltinator - I changed /etc/fstab to this entry.  No change in effect.  /dev/sr0  /mnt/dev/sr0  udf,iso9660  user,noauto,exec,utf8  0  0